# Factorization of Littlewood-Richardson Coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, littlewood-richardson-coefficients

For partitions $\mu \subset \lambda$, let $\kappa \subseteq \mu$ be a partition such that the shape $\lambda/\kappa$ contains at least two non-empty components $\lambda_i, i=1,2$, and similarly let $\mu_i\subset \lambda_i$ be the (possibly empty) corresponding components of $\mu/\kappa$.

(**EDIT**: these conditions are equivalent to saying that $\lambda/\mu$ has two connected components, $\lambda_1/\mu_1$ and $\lambda_2/\mu_2$)

For example, let $\mu = 5421$, $\lambda = 5533$, and $\kappa = 33$, then $\mu_1 = 21$, $\mu_2 = 21$, $\lambda_1 = 22$, $\lambda_2 = 33$.

For $\nu$ with $|\nu| = |\lambda|-|\mu|$, the Littlewood-Richardson coefficient $c_{\mu\nu}^{\lambda}$ clearly depends only on the data $\mu_i,\lambda_i, \nu$ (e.g. by looking at LR tableau).

**Question:** is there (or perhaps is it possible that there is) any 'factorization' formulae for the Littlewood-Richardson coefficient of the type:

$c_{\mu\nu}^{\lambda} = \sum_{\nu_1,\nu_2} c_{\mu_1,\nu_1}^{\lambda_1} c_{\mu_2,\nu_2}^{\lambda_2} f_{\nu}^{\nu_1,\nu_2},$

where $f_{\nu}^{\nu_1\nu_2}$ measures the 'splitting' of $\nu$ into two.

As a potential example, let $\lambda=321$, $\mu=\nu=21$, and $\kappa = 2$. Then have $\lambda_1=1$, $\lambda_2=21$, $\mu_1=\emptyset$, $\mu_2=1$. Then we might have a sum over the two decompositions $\nu = 2+1 = 1^2\cup 1$:

$2=c_{21,21}^{321} = c_{\emptyset,1}^{1} c_{1,1^2}^{21} + c_{\emptyset,1}^{1} c_{1,2}^{21} = 1+1.$

I'm aware of other 'factorization' type results for LR coefficients, such as King-Tollu-Toumazet "Factorisation of Littlewood–Richardson coefficients"  (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcta.2008.06.005), but that is a different kind of factorization.

This question was motivated by Conjecture 28 of Bravi-Gandini "Some combinatorial properties of skew jack symmetric functions" (https://doi.org/10.37236/10542)
(and my recent attempt to expand on it here: "The Stanley Conjecture Revisted" https://arxiv.org/abs/2401.01582)

Comment: It wasn't until I read Darij's answer that I understood your setup is that the skew shape $\lambda/\mu$ is the disjoint union of two smaller skew shapes $\lambda_1 / \mu_1$ and $\lambda_2 /\mu_2$. At least, I think this is how an algebraic combinatorialist would normally say it. Then the fact that if $\lambda/\mu=\lambda_1 / \mu_1\cup\lambda_2 /\mu_2$ we have $s_{\lambda/\mu} = s_{\lambda_1/\mu_1}s_{\lambda_2/\mu_2}$ is immediate from the combinatorial definition of skew Schur functions in terms of semistandard Young tableaux.

Comment: Indeed, in retrospect my formulation here is overly infected by my interest in the extension to Jack LR Coefficients.

Comment: In general I would say the vast majority of the time when working with skew shapes you really only want to consider the shapes (i.e., up to translation of connected components), not the partitions making them up. So $(2,1)/(1)$, $(3,2)/(2,1)$ and even $(2,1,1)/(1,1)$ should all be thought of as the same shape (namely, two independent boxes).

Comment: That's helpful thanks. But, am I correct in understanding that this is *not* true for skew Jack functions? I entered the world of working on symmetric function theory through Jacks (which certainly explains my ignorance on basic questions such as the above), and the preprint I recently put out (https://arxiv.org/abs/2401.01582) is an attempt to describe what happens when one translates the connected components of $\lambda/\mu$ around for the Jack LR coefficient. The answer, I conjecture, is simple but not obvious.

Comment: Yes, I suppose since the content of a box enters into the definition of Jack polynomials, and this is obviously not invariant under translation, what I said is not true at that level. But see also Section 2.4 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.00453 for discussion of what translation of skew shapes does to the Jack polynomial. EDIT: I see you cite this paper, so I'm sure I'm just telling you things you know. Sorry!

Comment: It’s safe to assume that I know little here! But yes, Per shared the Bravi-Gandini paper with me while I was trying to formulate my conjecture on these things - at the time I was mostly influenced by section 3. However, in the last week or so I’ve been giving section 2.4 a more thorough read (and corresponding with the authors), as it has far more in common with my preprint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, and in fact we can take $f_{\nu}^{\nu_{1},\nu_{2}}:=c_{\nu_{1},\nu_{2}}^{\nu}$.

To prove this, we recall the Schur functions $s_{\alpha}$ and the skew Schur
functions $s_{\alpha/\beta}$. (Keep in mind that $s_{\alpha/\beta}=0$ if
$\beta\not \subseteq \alpha$.) We furthermore recall the Hall inner product
$\left\langle \cdot,\cdot\right\rangle $ on the ring of symmetric functions.
It has the following two properties (among many others):

1. We have $c_{\beta,\gamma}^{\alpha}=\left\langle s_{\alpha/\beta
   },\ s_{\gamma}\right\rangle $ for any partitions $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$.
2. Any symmetric function $f$ satisfies $f=\sum_{\rho}\left\langle
   f,\ s_{\rho}\right\rangle s_{\rho}$, where the sum ranges over all partitions
   $\rho$.

Now, the conditions on $\lambda$, $\kappa$ and $\mu$ (if I understand them
correctly -- I think they are a bit imprecise) are saying that the shape
$\lambda/\mu$ decomposes into the disjoint union of two shapes $\lambda
_{1}/\mu_{1}$ and $\lambda_{2}/\mu_{2}$ that have no common rows or common
columns. As a consequence of this, we have
\begin{align*}
s_{\lambda/\mu}  & =s_{\lambda_{1}/\mu_{1}}s_{\lambda_{2}/\mu_{2}}\\
& =\left(  \sum_{\rho_{1}}\left\langle s_{\lambda_{1}/\mu_{1}},\ s_{\rho_{1}}
\right\rangle s_{\rho_{1}}\right)  \left(  \sum_{\rho_{2}}\left\langle
s_{\lambda_{2}/\mu_{2}},\ s_{\rho_{2}}\right\rangle s_{\rho_{2}}\right)  \\
& \qquad\qquad \left(
\begin{array}
[c]{c}
\text{since property 2 above}\\
\text{yields }s_{\lambda_{1}/\mu_{1}}=\sum_{\rho_{1}}\left\langle
s_{\lambda_{1}/\mu_{1}},\ s_{\rho_{1}}\right\rangle s_{\rho_{1}}\\
\text{and }s_{\lambda_{2}/\mu_{2}}=\sum_{\rho_{2}}\left\langle s_{\lambda
_{2}/\mu_{2}},\ s_{\rho_{2}}\right\rangle s_{\rho_{2}}
\end{array}
\right)  \\
& =\sum_{\rho_{1}}\ \ \sum_{\rho_{2}}\underbrace{\left\langle s_{\lambda
_{1}/\mu_{1}},\ s_{\rho_{1}}\right\rangle }_{
\substack{=c_{\mu_{1},\rho_{1}}^{\lambda_{1}}\\
\text{(by property 1 above)}}}\underbrace{\left\langle
s_{\lambda_{2}/\mu_{2}},\ s_{\rho_{2}}\right\rangle }_{\substack{=c_{\mu
_{2},\rho_{2}}^{\lambda_{2}}\\\text{(by property 1 above)}}}
\underbrace{s_{\rho_{1}}s_{\rho_{2}}}_{\substack{=\sum_{\rho}c_{\rho_{1},
\rho_{2}}^{\rho}s_{\rho}\\\text{(by the definition of}\\
\text{Littlewood--Richardson}\\\text{coefficients)}}}\\
& =\sum_{\rho_{1}}\ \ \sum_{\rho_{2}}c_{\mu_{1},\rho_{1}}^{\lambda_{1}}
c_{\mu_{2},\rho_{2}}^{\lambda_{2}}\sum_{\rho}c_{\rho_{1},\rho_{2}}^{\rho
}s_{\rho}\\
& =\sum_{\rho}\ \ \sum_{\rho_{1}}\ \ \sum_{\rho_{2}}c_{\mu_{1},\rho_{1}
}^{\lambda_{1}}c_{\mu_{2},\rho_{2}}^{\lambda_{2}}c_{\rho_{1},\rho_{2}}^{\rho
}s_{\rho}.
\end{align*}
Now, property 1 above yields
\begin{align*}
c_{\mu,\nu}^{\lambda}  & =\left\langle s_{\lambda/\mu},\ s_{\nu}\right\rangle
\\
& =\left\langle \sum_{\rho}\ \ \sum_{\rho_{1}}\ \ \sum_{\rho_{2}}c_{\mu
_{1},\rho_{1}}^{\lambda_{1}}c_{\mu_{2},\rho_{2}}^{\lambda_{2}}c_{\rho_{1}
,\rho_{2}}^{\rho}s_{\rho},\ s_{\nu}\right\rangle \\
& \qquad\qquad\left(  \text{since }s_{\lambda/\mu}=\sum_{\rho}\ \ \sum_{\rho_{1}
}\ \ \sum_{\rho_{2}}c_{\mu_{1},\rho_{1}}^{\lambda_{1}}c_{\mu_{2},\rho_{2}
}^{\lambda_{2}}c_{\rho_{1},\rho_{2}}^{\rho}s_{\rho}\right)  \\
& =\sum_{\rho_{1}}\ \ \sum_{\rho_{2}}c_{\mu_{1},\rho_{1}}^{\lambda_{1}}
c_{\mu_{2},\rho_{2}}^{\lambda_{2}}c_{\rho_{1},\rho_{2}}^{\nu}\qquad\qquad
\left(
\begin{array}
[c]{c}
\text{since the Schur functions }s_{\rho}\\
\text{form an orthonormal basis}\\
\text{with respect to the form }\left\langle \cdot,\cdot\right\rangle
\end{array}
\right)  \\
& =\sum_{\nu_{1}}\ \ \sum_{\nu_{2}}c_{\mu_{1},\nu_{1}}^{\lambda_{1}}c_{\mu
_{2},\nu_{2}}^{\lambda_{2}}c_{\nu_{1},\nu_{2}}^{\nu},
\end{align*}
as desired.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks very much. I had suspected that $f_{\nu}^{\nu_1,\nu_2} = c_{\nu_1\nu_2}^{\nu}$, but i wasnt sure. 
I wasnt aware of the factorization of Skew Schur functions $s_{\lambda/\mu} = s_{\lambda_1/\mu_1}s_{\lambda_2/\mu_2}$, from which this property follows straightforwardly. 
The conditions on $\mu,\nu$ and $\kappa$ are exactly as you describe, apologies for the imprecision.

Comment: General hint that has worked for me so far: Always think in terms of Schur functions, not in terms of LR coefficients.